# Support for android:state_first="true" in Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I have a apply a custom theme to an app where I use Jake Wharton's greate ViewPagerIndicator library. Unfortunately the theme requires the first and last of the Tab indicators to have rounded outer ends.

**It should look like so:**

[image: should look like so]

I thought I could implement this using a special `selector` drawable like the below (simplified), but obviously the state_first, state_middle, state_last are not supported - the background is simply blank when I use them, whilest it's okay (except for the outermost tabs) when I don't.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- middle buttons -->
<item android:state_middle="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/groupbutton_normal" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/groupbutton_pressed" />

<!-- first button -->
<item android:state_first="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/groupbutton_first_normal" />
<item android:state_first="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/groupbutton_first_pressed" />

<!-- lastbutton -->
<item android:state_last="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/groupbutton_first_normal" />
<item android:state_last="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/groupbutton_first_pressed" />

</selector>
```

It works without the `middle, first, last` states and looks like so then:

**Works only for this look:**

[image]

I already had a look at the code, but the tabs are just a bunch of `TabView`s (derived from `TextView`) within a `HorizontalScrollView` and I guess that doesn't support those state attributes.

So has anybody an implementation or an idea to solve this?

Comment: So annoying that nowhere on the whole internet a clear explanation of the use of android:state_first and android:state_last can be found. I also tried to use these for a Spinner dropdown but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I solved it by making three selectors, one for middle buttons, another one for first button and another for last button. Then I have to set the correct selector in the layout file for each button.

I know is just a workaround and doesn't solve the android:state_first="true" question, but at least your layout will look fine.

Answer (score 0):

By searching in the Android source code it looks like it's only mentioned in some animation file's documentation. And declared as a resource/attribute in the R class. Period.

I searched in API 21, 22, and 25.

So yes, it looks like "not used at all".

**Implementing states by ourselves**

You could extend a class and implement it. If you are already creating your own view, or it's a suitable solution.

In that case:

```
enum class Position(val stateIds: IntArray) {
  FIRST(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_first)),
  MIDDLE(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_middle)),
  LAST(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_last))
}

class YourView {

var position: Position = Position.MIDDLE
  set(value) {
    field = value
    // tell Android state changed
    refreshDrawableState()
  }


// tell Android the current state: parent class state + position state
override fun onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace: Int): IntArray {
  return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1).also {
      // one small issue is this method gets called in parent's initialization
      // before this class's fields got initialized. So you can
      // use a nullable field and check for null here, maybe.
      // Which would work as "NONE" value.
      View.mergeDrawableStates(it, stateIds)
    }
}
```